# PHP - Forms only using last row in form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that generates a number of rows according to how many rows are in the database, but the submit button is only taking the last row in the table and not the one I selected. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                ?>

<form class='table-form' id='form' method='post'>

                    <tr>

                    <input id="bookid" type="hidden" name="bookid" value="<?php echo ($row['booking_id']); ?>" />

                    <td>

                    <input id="bookingid"<?php echo ($row['booking_id']);?>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['event_id']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['payment_type']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['booking_date']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="cancel" name="cancel" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                <?php
                }
                ?>


                </form>

            </table>
        </div>

        <?php

                if (isset($_POST['bookid'])){

                $bookid = ($_POST['bookid']);

                $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM booking
                WHERE booking_id = '$bookid'");
                }
?>
```

Comment: Deprecated functions are the least of your problems.  You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, as your code makes no attempt to escape the data being used in your query.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: This doesn't really show/explain too much. Could you please tidy your code a bit and add anything else relevant to the question

Comment: so how are you looping through the sql results? `while`? `foreach`? where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @andrew apologies, added the while in.

Comment: @user3191346 what will you do when someone enters `asdf'; DROP TABLE booking --'` as the value for the bookid field using a hijacked version of your form?

Comment: @reformed — Not a lot I suspect since, IIRC, PHP only allows one query per call. It is subqueries that are the risk.

Comment: @reformed No one will be doing that due to the fact this is not going public. I am learning PHP.

Comment: @user3191346 If your practice is sloppy don't be surprised when you play sloppily

Answer (score 1):

All your inputs have the same name and that name does not end in the characters `[]`. PHP will therefore only accept the last value.

Rename them to include `[]` at the end of the name if you want them to all be available.

Additionally, you are generating invalid HTML. Browsers may move elements placed in invalid parts of tables so they are outside the table when they try to recover from this type of error. This could cause you more problems. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org) to identify the errors, and fix them.

Comment: +1 also my ide is suggesting that forms may not be embedded in tables

Comment: @andrew — That's not the only error of that nature, hence the third paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Like so? input id="bookid" type="hidden" name="bookid[]" value="<?php echo ($row['booking_id']); ?>" />

Comment: Yes. (Although `id`s must be unique in a document, so you can't use a fixed value for them in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple elements with the 'same name' you need to have their names defined in an array like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="bookid[]" value="<?php echo ($row['booking_id']); ?>" />
```

When you process the form you can read them like this, and treat them like an array:

```
$bookids = $_POST['bookid'];

foreach($bookids as $eachBookId)
{ do some processing ... }
```